# Recomended home ADSL wireless routers

Tags: wireless-router

I'm going to buy a new ADSL wireles broadband router, but i'm not sure what might be a good one. I want it to have some form of QOS on it, and SNMP support so i can see my port usage over MRGT.

I've looked at various models but they all seem to have conflicting reviews, i am looking at something along the lines of the [Dlink DSL-2740R](http://www.dlink.co.uk/cs/Satellite?c=Product_C&childpagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLProductCarousel&cid=1197380299994&p=1197318962342&packedargs=ParentPageID%3D1197318962321%26TopLevelPageProduct%3DConsumer%26locale%3D1195806691854%26packedargs%3DProductParentID%253D1195808621247&pagename=DLinkEurope-GB%2FDLWrapper) but any suggestions would be much apreciated

Comment: Sorry, but shopping type questions are discouraged on SU. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/not-the-shopping